# AVDMANAGER -> Error: Invalid --tag default for the selected package

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, android-virtual-device, macos-sierra

```
$ avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-24;google_apis;x86"
```

> Error: Invalid --tag default for the selected package.

How to solve this error?

Comment: Same here, haven't managed to fix it yet

Comment: any luck solving this issue ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `--abi google_apis/x86` flag.

Comment: why exactly `--abi`? can you please share a link with explanation?

Comment: ok, just google it ;) . https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html

Comment: Use `--abi google_apis/x86_64` for 64-bit systems. Useful guide: https://handstandsam.com/2016/04/23/using-the-android-emulator-for-continuous-integration/

Answer (score 2):

The data store that the sdkmanager v26.1.1 uses is out of date.

Update your tools with:

```
sdkmanager --update
```

It will then have the updated tags to choose from. One can also run:

```
avdmanager -v create avd -g google_apis -n Android-27 -k "system-images;android-27;google_apis;x86"
```

But always better to run with updated tools.